# Is there a way to automatically make a "collage" of plots with matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a Python script using pandas and matplotlib that outputs 4 plots into individual PNG files. This part is fine. I would also like to make all 4 plots into a collage automatically - nothing fancy, just all 4 plots plotted next to each other is fine - and output that collage image as another (5th) PNG file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [plt.subplots()](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html). This allows you to add multiple plots to the same figure. You can configure the rows and columns to make a 2x2 grid or 4x1 or 1x4.

Another option, if you want more control of subplot size, is [Matplotlib Gridspec](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html).